# Python cx_Oracle bind list of variables

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

How can I use bind parameters with variable parameters, for example I would prepare in python dynamically an insert all statement, and would like to bind it with rows of data.

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (:expr[0][0], :expr[0][1], :expr[0][n])
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (:expr[1][0], :expr[1][n], :expr[1][n])
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (:expr[n][0], :expr[n][1], :expr[n][n])
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Is this possible using `cx_oracle` on python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting your real question as 'how do I insert lots of data efficiently in cx_Oracle', the answer is not to use INSERT ALL.  Instead you should use executemany():

```
data = [
    (60, "Parent 60"),
    (70, "Parent 70"),
    (80, "Parent 80"),
    (90, "Parent 90"),
    (100, "Parent 100")
]

cursor.executemany("""
        insert into ParentTable (ParentId, Description)
        values (:1, :2)""", data)
```

This is all described in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle